# Issues with opening KML/KMZ with google maps api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am having issues with overlaying a kml that I have created and have hosted on google drives and locally, with neither working. The documentation with google api help says only a kml that   is "publically available" is able to be embeded. How can I get my custom KML/KMZ to be able to embed?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
<body style="background-color:#FFFFFF;"> </body>

<style type="text/css" media="all">

h2 { font: 2em Times serif; color: #FF9900; }
h1 { font: 2em Times serif; color: #FF9900; }
h3{font: 2em Times serif; color: #003300; }
h1{text-align:top;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 10px;
margin-left: 0px;
z-index: 5;  
}
h2{text-align:top;
position: fixed;
top: 40px;
left: 10px;
margin-left: 0px;
z-index: 5;

}

h3{text-align:top;
position: fixed;
font-size:20px;
top: 100px;
left: 10px;
margin-left: 0px;
z-index: 5;
}
</style>
<h1>Company</h1>
<h2>Business Satisfaction Group</h2>
<h3> ENTER AN ADDRESS AND HIT FIND!</h3>

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>company</title>
<style>
html, body, #map-canvas {

height: 70%;
margin: 150px;
padding: 50px;
top: -360px;
left:-520px;

}
#panel {
position: absolute;
top:150px;
left: 10%;
margin-left: -150px;
z-index: 5;
background-color: #003300;
padding: 5px;
border: 0px solid #FFFFFF;
}

img {
position: absolute;
left: 1500px;
top: 50px;
z-index: -1;
}

</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script>
var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.089411, -94.579096);
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 10,
center: latlng
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.879894,-94.617853);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker();

// Function to load KML overlay\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
var KML_Overlay = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
url: 'Local URL from my '
});
KML_Overlay.setMap(map);




}



function codeAddress() {
var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
map: map,
position: results[0].geometry.location
});
} else {
alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
}
});
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>  
</head>
<body>



<div id="panel">
<input id="address" type="textbox" value="">
<input type="button" value="FIND" onclick="codeAddress()">
</div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the "publicly available URL" for the KML you are trying to load?  The code posted doesn't attempt to load any KML.

Comment: I edited my code and added the function for adding a kml layer. Sorry, I omitted that. My issue is that I have a kml stored locally, which I created showing zip code boundaries of the kansas city area. I can successfully add a KML example from googles api code samples, which is hosted by google, but cannot add a kml that I created myself. I don't know how to upload a kml to this forum to provide, but could share it with my google apps account?

Comment: This is not a forum.  You can post the contents of a (small) KML in your question.  A KML file on your local computer can't be used on a Google Maps (or a Google Maps Javascript API) map.  It must be on a publicly accessible web server.  Your google apps account might work, if there is publicly available space there (not password protected), I don't have a google apps account.